# BUCLE INFINITO HIBERNATE APIREST

Tags: java, api, spring, hibernate, rest

hola que tal actualmente estoy haciendo un proyecto con estas tecnologias

- HIBERNATE ( PARA CREAR ENTIDADES Y DEMAS )
- JPA ( CONEXIONES ETC. )
- JDBC ( CONEXIONES DE OTRO TIPO )
- SPRING MVC ( PARA CREAR EL CONTROLADOR y RETORNAR LOS JSON )

el detalle es que tengo muy poca experiencia con hibernate..

actualmente tengo este tipo de ejemplo en las relaciones @onetomany

```
@Entity
public class Recetas implements Serializable {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String Nombre;
    private String imagenUrl;
    private int minutos;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recetas_id")
    private List<Ingredientes> ingredientes = new ArrayList<>();
```

que hace una relación con ingredientes ( ya que una receta puede tener varios ingredientes )

```
 @Entity
public class Ingredientes {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recetas_id", nullable = false)
    private Recetas recetas_id;
```

y hago un joincolumn para referencias al padre y tener una relación bidireccional  de

el detalle esta en que cuando intento extraer los datos en json me hace un bucle infinito

ya que como podran ver un padre tiene un hijo y el hijo hace referencia al padre .. y pues se hace un bucle hacia dentro

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Huevos",
    "recetas_id": {
        "id": 1,
        "imagenUrl": "http://google.com.mx",
        "minutos": 10,
        "ingredientes": [],
        "nombre": "Huevos con chorizo "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de evitar lo que comentas es indicando qué atributos no quieres que se incluyan en la respuesta JSON. Para ello hay varias opciones, pero la más simple es usar la anotación **com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore** (está en el paquete com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.5)

Quedaría así tu entidad:

```
@Entity
public class Ingredientes {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String nombre;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recetas_id", nullable = false)
    private Recetas recetas_id;

    ....
}
```

El controlador de Spring, cuando vaya a procesar el objeto a devolver como JSON, al encontrar esa anotación, obviará el atributo.

Otra opción sería que creases unos DTO, en los que no tuvieses esa relación hijo->padre y que fuesen esos DTO los que devolvieses, creándolos a partir de las entidades que has recuperado vía JPA, aunque yo soy más partidario de usar la anotación.

PD: Fíjate que tal y como has diseñado las entidades, una receta tiene varios ingredientes, pero un ingrediente sólo podrá estar en una receta.

Comment: ok tendria que checarlo la verdad es que no lo e probado un dto podria ser un VO ? un objeto donde se almacenara los datos que retorna la consulta ?

Comment: Sí, un DTO (Data Transfer Object) viene a ser lo mismo que un VO (Value Object): objetos sin lógica que sólo sirven para intercambio de datos